# Pikamoon not showing value in TrustWallet

Tags: ethereumj

I recently got on the Pikamoon train. I claimed my tokens as a 3rd round investor today. The tokens went into my trust wallet and are shown there, but they have no value. My buddies have coinbase wallet and they were able to see the value of the coin, and presumably sell it. I cannot. Can anyone lend any insight ?

Comment: Using a block explorer check the tokens in your address. It could be that you bought an scam token with the same name. If you have the correct token you should ask the Trust Wallet customer support if they show the correct value.